# Symfony2 choice options are overridden when option text is duplicated

Tags: php, symfony

Currently I am working on building a select box for phone country extensions. My select box is like this.

```
<option value="Albania">355</option>
...

<option value="Canada">1</option>
...
```

I provide an array as choices for the select field in the Symfony form.
array is like this.

```
array(
'Albania' => 355,
'Afganisthan' => 93,
...
'Canada' => 1,
...
...
'United States Of America' => 1
);
```

But, when I render the form, the list rendered is bit strange. I cannot see **Canada** option. Instead, it is replaced by **United States Of America**.

I guess it is because of the option text is the same **(1 and 1)**.

This was working before until I upgrade my Symfony version from **2.4** to **2.7**. I went through the Symfony documentation but not enough lucky to find any related thing.

Why this happens?

Comment: how are you rendering your list of extensions?

Comment: Field is rendered in normal way. Like {{ form_widget(form.phone_country) }}

Comment: I was able to find this [article](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization) about the refactorization of Choice Type in Symfony version 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this. Cannot say it is a perfect solution.

I added the choice_as_values as true to my field. And added the choice_value callback. Helped (this)[https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14377#issuecomment-107872604] advise. It helped me to make it not flipped.